# EntityFramework Core returns wrong data when I use Oracle provider (Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore)

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

I use ef core (v.5) with oracle.EntityFrameworkCore (v.3 or v.5, whatever) as provider for Oracle (v.19). When I call .ToList() it should return all records in a table, but there are some mistakes. Let's check the code:

```cs
using var ctx = new MyContext(optionsWithConnectionString);
var targetElementsInMemory = ctx.TargetTable.ToList();
var targetElementsDbSet = ctx.TargetTable;
_ = targetElementsInMemory.Count == targetElementsDbSet.Count(); // <- true
string stringForChecking = "some string";
_ = targetElementsInMemory.Any(x => x.TextColumnt == someString); // <- false
_ = targetElementsDbSet.Any(x => x.TextColumnt == someString); // <- true (it should be true, because it exists in database)
_ = targetElementsInMemory.GroupBy(x => x.AnyProperty).Select(x => x.Count()).OrderByDescending().First(); // <- 200
_ = targetElementsDbSet.GroupBy(x => x.AnyProperty).Select(x => x.Count()).OrderByDescending().First(); // <- 100 This is true
```

Actually, I don't know a reason of the problem. But I see, that some element was overridden during materialization.

Has someone faced such a problem?

Comment: Analyse SQL, but looks like your database(columns) has Case Insensitive collation.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Hi. thanks you the answer. The sql is correct. it happens even if I use direct sql query from ef core, like: select * from [table]. Btw, if I use nhibernate, of course, the result is correct. but I would avoid a pain by orm changing.

Comment: So compare NHibernate SQL and EF Core, there should be differences. Most probably with Collation.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv generated request text is different (ef: select "d"."Col1" from "table" "d", nH: select d.Col1 from table d;) but no problem here. Even if I use manual select from ef (select * from table) the problem exists. I don't see any problem with collation

Comment: You have to compare WHERE, not SELECT part.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I have no WHERE statement in query to db. only select. "where" function in example occurs in memory.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv If you mean comparing nhibernate and ef generated query, I think. In provided example, if I use where in db query - data is correct, in contrary if I fetch all rows to memory - some data invalid. Anyway, WHERE part is correct in ef or nhibernate, whatever.